# Why there are public methods in Obejct class, they could have been protected?

Tags: java

Why methods in Object class like equals(), hashcode() etc. are public. If those would have protected, it would have suffice the requirements. Please explain.

Comment: You should read about the difference between modifiers.

Comment: Which requirements? Hash sets require those two methods to exist to function properly. It could be arguable that they should've been in a separate interface though (thus public).

Answer (score 3):

Wrong.

You cannot call a `protected` method from a base class except on a qualifier that is at least of your type.

Had `toString()` been protected, code in `class A {}` would only be able to call `toString()` on instances of `A`.

Comment: I still can not understand it properly. can you please explain with an example. when i run the below program it runs fine.             class Superclass{
 
 protected void MyMethod(){
  System.out.println("Inside superclass method");
 }
 
 Superclass obj1 = new Superclass();

 
}    output: Inside superclass method
Inside superclass method


public class MyClass extends Superclass{

 public static void main(String s[]){
  
  Superclass obj1 = new Superclass();
  obj1.MyMethod();
  
  Superclass obj2 = new MyClass();
  obj2.MyMethod();
  
 }
}

Comment: @SandyDrake You can't call a protected method from another class.  This means you couldn't use `toString()` in String append or println, you couldn't use hashCode() in a HashMap and you couldn't use equals() in a List.

Comment: @SandyDrake: That's because `protected` methods are also visible inside the package.  Move `MyClass` to a different package and that will stop compiling.

Comment: Got your point now. Thanks all for making me clear here!